# error in your SQL syntax: when passing nested query in executeQuery() method

Tags: java, mysql

Sorry for such a silly question.

**below is the actual query:**

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(b.maxtime, "%H:%i") as ts, b.max_value-b.min_value as 
diff FROM (SELECT max(Anzahl) as max_value ,min(Anzahl) as min_value,  
greatest(max(ts),min(ts)) as maxtime  
FROM customer where ts rlike '^2017-06-06' and Typ="B4A"
GROUP BY hour(ts)) b;
```

**And when I am passing it in `executeQuery()` method using java like below:**

```
resultset =statement.executeQuery("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(b.maxtime,\"%H:%i\") 
as ts, b.max_value-b.min_value as diff(SELECT max(Anzahl) as max_value 
,min(Anzahl) as min_value, max(ts) as maxtime from customer where Typ = " + 
"\"" + selected_value+"\""+" "+"and ts RLIKE"+"'^"+cal_value+"'"+ "GROUP BY 
hour(ts))b");
```

**I am getting error in SQL syntax.**
**and Error is**:

> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'(SELECT max(Anzahl) as max_value ,min(Anzahl) as min_value, max(ts) as maxtime f'` at line 1

Can someone help me out to figure out the problem.

Comment: Single quotes around B4A perhaps?

Comment: You have some missing spaces in there, which is probably what is causing the error.  But you should learn about prepared statements, which would help to avoid this problem.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I think MySQL will accept either single or double quotes.

Comment: It shouldn't.  Double quotes have a different meaning entirely.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem they have no difference in my local mysql database(5.0),I think it might has something to do with the version

Comment: Oh, maybe.  It wouldn't surprise me if MySQL had some non-standard syntax.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No he hasn't missed any spaces. Highlight the query using your mouse and you'll see there are spaces at the end of the each line.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala I missed the space before the `and`.  But for crying out loud, _use a statement_ please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo. In the actual query there's a `FROM` after `...b.min_value as 
diff`. You have left it out in the String which you are parsing to `executeQuery()`

```
...diff FROM (SELECT max(Anzahl)...
```

---

So the complete statement would be

```
resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(b.maxtime,\"%H:%i\") 
as ts, b.max_value-b.min_value as diff FROM (SELECT max(Anzahl) as max_value 
,min(Anzahl) as min_value, max(ts) as maxtime from customer where Typ = " + 
"\"" + selected_value+"\""+" "+"and ts RLIKE"+"'^"+cal_value+"'"+ "GROUP BY 
hour(ts))b");
```

Comment: My pleasure... :)